# Получение ссылки на панораму

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть строка, содержащая адрес некоего дома. Есть ли возможность получить ссылку на панораму этого дома? Встраивать панораму не нужно, просто ссылка.

В описании API не нашёл, в поисковике нашёл только одно обращение 2009 года, когда у панорам еще было API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для мобильных Яндекс.Карт есть публичная url-схема, которая позволяет открыть панораму в нужной точке. [Вот документация.](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-android-app-docpage/#streetview)

Чтобы открыть панораму рядом с домом, вам потребуется сначала получить его координаты через [Геокодер](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/?from=SO). Но при этом направление взгляда на панораме может быть неверным и панорама может загрузиться "спиной" к нужному дому.

Для web-версии Яндекс.Карт официальной url-схемы нет, но вы можете подобрать параметры самостоятельно и действовать аналогично.